# asp.net validation message position

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a registration form where each field have a validation message beside it, and the problem is there are some fields that has more than one validation message so their position will be a little bit away from its field like this:

[image]

so when I test the validation the (email required) message will be on the top of the field and the (wrong email form) message will be below. and my question is how can I put the three messages in the same position in the right of the field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "Validation Summary"
Set your validators to Display=None

and then add the validation summary in the position you would like to display the validators messages:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary id="valSummary" runat="server"
    HeaderText="Review your input, the following errors occurred:"
     ShowSummary="true" DisplayMode="List" />
```

For more references check [here](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/10/validationsummary-example-how-to-use.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have also found that **only one error will show up at a time**. so it only looks bad in design view. when running, if someone does not enter an address, only the 'required' error will show; if the email is taken, obviously something has been entered, so only the 'taken' error will show; if it's the wrong format, only the 'wrong format' error will show.